# How to hide control center status bar in Theos tweak?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I'm starting my adventure with creating tweaks for a jailbroken iPhone. I installed the FLEXing tweak from the NSCake repo and while browsing through the headers I encountered a problem. I want to hide control center status bar, but the code doesn't work. I've tried using `-(void)setHidden` and `-(void)isHidden`.

Tweak.x:

```
%hook CCUIStatusBar
    -(void)setHidden:(bool)hidden {
        %orig(YES);
    }
%end
```

Makefile:
`Renegade_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS = ControlCenterUI MaterialKit SpringBoardUI`